# JobSchedule JobInfo.TriggerContentUrl does not trigger when app is closed forcefully

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-jobscheduler

```
JobInfo.Builder builder = new JobInfo.Builder(JobIds.PHOTOS_CONTENT_JOB,
                    new ComponentName("com.example.android.apis", PhotosContentJob.class.getName()));
// Only Trigger when app is Open or in Background
builder.addTriggerContentUri(new JobInfo.TriggerContentUri(CallLog.CONTENT_URI,
                    JobInfo.TriggerContentUri.FLAG_NOTIFY_FOR_DESCENDANTS));
builder.build();
```

After Android M BroadCast cannot fired if app is forcefully killed. I was trying to use alternative JobScheduler JobInfo.TriggerContentUri but it is only trigger when app is open or in background if app is closed or forcefully killed then it is not triggering. `setPersisted()` will fired when device reboot.
Is there any way that i can achive trigger using JobScheduler when app is closed.

Any guide or help will be appriciated.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: All alarms and jobs are cancelled when your app is force stopped. It is literally the signal that your app should not run again

Comment: @ianhanniballake there is any way achive this or fired broadcast when app is closed app like Truecaller in PlayStore still working. I found this app https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.vladlee.callblocker&hl=en at Play Store this is still working when is closed

Comment: Force close just terminates the OS processes hosting your app. There isn't a way to trigger something as you get no warning. When your app has been force closed, the user must manually start it again for it to run or be able to receive broadcast `Intent`s or whatever.  You could install another app that acts as a "watchdog" and ensures that your app is always restarted or reenabled after force close, but the user could also force close that app. They would need to watch each other...